# JIRA - BitBucket. How to see rejected pull request?

Tags: git, bitbucket, jira, pull-request

I work with GIT repository on Bitbucket - JIRA with my team. I push commits and do pull requests.

Normally my reviewer accepts pull request and merges my commit to main branch. Though sometimes my pull request is declined - means it have some not fixed problems.

But how can I see my previous pull requests and comments to them, especially declined ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also filter in bitbucket your self, default filter is Open

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

on bitbucket you can see declined PRs at:

https://bitbucket.org/OWNER/REPO/pull-requests/?state=DECLINED